# Why is my training curve and validation curve on the same level and how to find a proper architecture for an ANN?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, validation

I have build a neural network model. All in all it doesn't work properly, but since it is part of my Master Thesis I've to evaluate it and find some explanations.

The learning curve looks like this:

[image]

And the validation curve looks like this:

[image]

Some questions to this:

How can it be that learning and validation curves for training and validation are quite the same? Is there an error in the model or is this quite common (for underfitting models)?

How to find the best architecture of a MLPClassifier? I have 7 input features and 7 classes in the target (~ 800.000 datapoints). If I start with 1 hidden layer and 10 neurons, I get an acc of ~43 %. If I increase the number of layers and neurons, the acc gets better, up to ~ 55-60%, but the validation time is also increasing very much. For example: training and validation with 1 layer and 10 neurons lasts up to a few minutes, and training and validation with 100 in one, two or three layers takes hours. When should I stopp with increasing the number of neurons and layers, what is a sufficient training time and when does it take definetely too long?

The code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

start_time = time.time()

train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores =\
    learning_curve(estimator = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (100,), max_iter=500), X = X_train, y = y_train, train_sizes = np.linspace(0.1,1,5), cv  = 3, n_jobs = -1)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time))

train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)

plt.plot(train_sizes, train_mean,
         color = "blue", marker = 'o',
         markersize = 5,label  ='Training accuracy')

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, 
                 train_mean + train_std, 
                 train_mean - train_std,
                 alpha=0.15, color = 'blue')

plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, 
         color='red', linestyle = '--',
         marker = 's',markersize = 5, 
         label = 'Validation accuracy')

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, 
                 test_mean + test_std, 
                 test_mean - test_std,
                 alpha=0.15, color = 'green')
    

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Number of training examples')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.ylim([0.25, 1.01])
plt.show
```

Thanks for help

---EDIT---

I am trying to classify soil classes based on laboratory tests but with data from field tests (CPT) as input. There are 7 soil classes which can be classified and the data from the field test has no known empirical or statistical relationship with the classes, so basically I am trying to find  those patterns with the machine learning model...

Answer (score 1):

The number of neurons and layers ultimately depends on the task that needs to be solved by the NN, which you haven't told us anything about.

Assuming that you're doing binary classification an accuracy of 50% is of course no better than random guessing. It appears that there's a problem "outside" the Neural Network. This could be that there is no predictive relation between the input features and the class. It could also be the problem that your data is not normalized. If your MLP uses an activation function that expects the input to be within a certain range, than it's important that your features are normalized to that range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I am trying to classify soil classes based on laboratory tests but with data from field tests (CPT). There are 7 soil classes which can be classified and the data from the field test has no known empirical or statistical relationship with the classes, so basically I am trying to find  those patterns with machine learning...(I'll edit my initial question).

Comment: Additionally, that learning curve shows that model's performance is not increasing as the sample size grows so you should indeed try another model since the one you have chosen is not explaining the phenomena, additionally you should consider the class distribution and evaluate via confusion matrix if there is/are ca class/classes that your model is struggling with.In your place I would start with a simple model (say a neural net with one single neuron and sigmoid activation i.e LogisticRegression)